# Adding a feature to a data frame using wise functions inside a customer transformer

Tags: python-3.x, pandas, machine-learning, scikit-learn

I have the following class:

```
class AddFeature(BaseEstimator, TransformerMixin):

    def __init__(self, mark_cat=True, sex_age=False):
        self.mark_cat = mark_cat
        self.sex_age = sex_age 

    def fit(self, X, y=None):
        return self 

    def add_cat(self, X, y=None):
        if X.G3 >= 10:
            return 1
        else :
            return 0

    def transform(self, X, y=None):

        if self.mark_cat:
            X['mark_cat'] = X.apply(add_cat, axis='columns')
            return X
```

I want to add a feature called `mark_cat` based on `G3` value(which a column in my data frame)
When i run the pipeline transformation i get the following error

`AttributeError: 'Series' object has no attribute 'G3'`

How can i do this please ?

Answer (score 1):

Using `apply` applies the function to each column, so in that call to `add_cat`, `X` is a `Series` not a `DataFrame`, hence the error.

Anyway, if I understand the question correctly, this is a bit easier:

```py
class AddFeature(BaseEstimator, TransformerMixin):

    def __init__(self, mark_cat=True):
        self.mark_cat = mark_cat

    def fit(self, X, y=None):
        return self 

    def transform(self, X, y=None):
        if self.mark_cat:
            X['mark_cat'] = X['G3'].apply(lambda x: 1 if x >= 10 else 0)
        return X
```

Of course, this is really fragile; you may want to add some checks, an input for the column name and threshold, etc.